# Need Putting Javascript into CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have JavaScript code and css code. i need Putting JavaScript into CSS

JavaScript -

```
function load(){
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 if (userAgent .indexOf('safari')!=-1){
   if(userAgent .indexOf('chrome')  > -1){

   }else{

  **//NEED ADD CODE HEARE**

   }
  }
}
```

css code -

`nav#good {margin-top:-22px;}`

place help me friends..

(i need work only css safari browser)

Comment: Your question says you want to put some JavaScript code into some CSS code. That will not work. It looks like you actually want to inject some CSS using JavaScript. Is that more correct?

Comment: Please adjust your question and add more information about your goal.

Comment: yes. you are correct..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set inline CSS styles with JavaScript:

`document.getElementById('good').style.marginLeft = "-22px";`

See in example below:

```js
document.getElementById('good').style.marginLeft = "-22px";
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}

#good {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="good">Hey i'm margin-left: -22px</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Really? Check code snippet example. Maybe you aren't linking up your javascript correctly. Please provide your full code.